# how do I change font color in html

Tags: html, css, colors, font-family, inline-styles

the relevant part of my code is:

```
<p style="font-family:'impact', color:red">
            something          
</p>
```

The problem is I can't use both the color and the font together.
If I use the `font-family` property alone, it works perfectly.
If I use the `color` property alone, it works perfectly.
But if I use both properties together, as shown above, neither of them work.

What error am I making in my inline style code? What is the proper way to use the style attribute to change multiple CSS properties?

Comment: You need to replace the comma with a semicolon.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept an answer so that others can also benefit in case of a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the style attribute to apply a unique style to a single paragraph element, you should include a semicolon after each CSS property.

```html
<p style="color: red;">
This text is red
</p>

<p style="font-family: impact;">
This text is impact font
</p>

<p style="color: red; font-family: impact;">
This text is red and impact font
</p>
```

Comment: works perfectly, I realize now how it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Write it like that:

```
<p style="font-family:'impact'; color:red"></p>
```

Comment: works perfectly, didn't realize that, thank you so much.